# RXJava - how to get the value when onErrorReturn is invoked

Tags: rx-java

using rx java I implement onErrorReturn() on an obserable.
Is there a way to know which item caused the exception to be thrown?
I only have Throable trhow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some operators will attach a value-cause to the exception sent through `onError`. You can try and look for `OnNextValue` instances in the exception's cause chain.